# Symfony 4.2 How to do a service public only for tests

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have the solution to make the service public. In the services.yml

```
    test_phpdocxService:
          alias: App\Service\PhpDocxService
          public: true
```

I try to access the service:

```
$container = self::$container;
$phpDocxService = $container->get('test_phpdocxService');

$this->filename = $phpDocxService->generateDocxDocument('docx/aaa.html.twig', $data);
```

But I find it not so nice. Is there an another way to do that?

Comment: Does [simpler-service-testing](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-simpler-service-testing) not work for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't  work in Symfony 4.2

Comment: Consider updating your question with a bit of test code.  Keep it as simple as possible just showing how you are trying to access your doc service.

Comment: Ok. I done it .

Comment: Normally I appreciate brevity in a question.  Having to skim though hundreds of lines of code is mind numbing but, in this case, I think we need just a tiny bit more.  Copy/Paste the WebTestCase in the linked example and then tweak the service name.  Do you get a "service not found error"?

Comment: I get the message: Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException : The "test_phpdocxService" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

Comment: Using the approach in the linked article, you should be asking for "App\Service\PhpDocxService", not "test_phpdocxService"

Comment: I also doen't work
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException : The "App\Service\PhpDocxService" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

I do `$phpDocxService = $container->get(\App\Service\PhpDocxService::class);`

Answer (score 9):

Okay.  So there is an [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/27741) about testing private services that are not used anywhere in your app.  It is still open and being discussed but basically, for now, you need to typehint against your private service somewhere in your app before you can access it in a test.

Using a fresh 4.4.2 install:

```
# src/Service/PhpDocxService.php
namespace App\Service;
class PhpDocxService
{
    public function sayHello()
    {
        return 'hello';
    }
}

# src/Controller/MyController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Service\PhpDocxService;


class MyController
{
    #****** This is the secret ******
    public function __construct(PhpDocxService $phpDocxService)
    {

    }
}

# src/tests/MyTest.php
namespace App\Tests;

use App\Service\PhpDocxService;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class MyTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testServiceFound()
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        // gets the special container that allows fetching private services
        $container = self::$container;

        $phpDocxService = $container->get(PhpDocxService::class);

        $this->assertEquals('hello',$phpDocxService->sayHello());
    }
}
```

Typehint your service in a controller's constructor and everything works as expected.

Comment: The service is now in using.

`
public function testPhpdocx(PhpDocxService $phpDocxService)
    {
 
 
    }

Comment: @olek07 Not sure what you mean.  You can't inject services into test methods.  Still need to pull them from the container.  You just need to inject it somewhere in your app to avoid having it being deleted as unused when the container is compiled.

Comment: Yes, it's already injected in the action testPhpdocx. This action is a normal action, it has nothing to do with unit test despite of prefix test

Comment: It doesn't work also in the consructor
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException : The "App\Service\PhpDocxService" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

Comment: I think, my mistake was I have forgotten `self::bootKernel();`

Comment: @olek07 I'm guessing by now you are getting pretty frustrated with whole thing.  Probably tried lots of approaches.  Take a break.  Then comeback and create a new project.  Add the three files I posted above and verify it works as expected.  Which it will.  Then maybe go back and figure out why it does not work in your current project.  And yes, booting the kernel is kind of important.

Comment: It works without injecting the service into the constructor. What is the secret now?

Comment: @olek07 Just ran a quick test and action injection does seem to work.  Cool.  In my case, not injecting anywhere results in the service not found.

Comment: But not with the service mocking 
`$container->set(\App\Service\PhpDocxService::class, $someService); ` generates the message
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException : The "App\Service\PhpDocxService" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

Comment: I don't see anything about service mocking in your question.  Whole different issue and something best avoided if possible.

Comment: I thought with this solution it is possible to mock private services

Comment: Thanks, @Cerad, for deciphering what "unused service" stands for!

Comment: Adding a constructor argument that won't be used anywhere in the class, just to enable unit testing is not recommended. It's way better to use a test config file, where the needed service is made public.

Answer (score 8):

You need to create in `config/config_test.yml` and declare that service is public and other configuration for tests there .

This approach you can use in symfony 3/4.

You can read tutorial here: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/phpunit/integration-tests

About [Symfony simple testing 4.1 feature](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-simpler-service-testing) please read @Cerad post

Answer (score 3):

**YOU DON'T! :)**

Instead, you use the new [Simpler service testing](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-simpler-service-testing), implemented in Symfony 4.1.

With that, *tests based on WebTestCase and KernelTestCase now access to a special container via the  static::$container property that allows fetching non-removed private services*.

And that means that private services are automatically public in tests if you use that container.

Just do something like:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class SomeClassToTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function getService(string $service)
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
        $container = self::$container;

        return self::$container->get($service);
    }

    public function tesSomething()
    {
        $imageProcessor = $this->getService('app.some.service');
    }
```

And now you can get the private 'app.some.service' service in testing environments.

Comment: Of course it does O.o I use it in my projects and I use Symfony 4.2

Comment: Can confirm this works too. Just be careful you don't boot the kernel twice.

Comment: Can confirm, do not bot the kernel twice

Answer (score 0):

The **autowiring** exists Since Symfony 3.4 but with the 4.x version, it is activated by default.

So, all your class inside /src directory is public and setted as services.

Go to ***/config/services.yaml***, you'll find this code:

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

This means that your ***/src/Services/PhpDocxService.php*** file is callable by ***App/Services/PhpDocxService***

The solution what you found is to call your service by `$this->getContainer()->get('test_phpdocxService');`

Comment: Yes, but I think, it's a bad solution to define the aliases in services.yml only for tests. Is there a better way?