# Symfony 4. Special container that allows fetching private services

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, symfony4

On the page https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-simpler-service-testing stands

```
// gets the special container that allows fetching private services
$container = self::$container;
```

But it takes no effect for me in functional tests. Only when I define the service as public, I can use `$container->set('service.mail', $someService);`

What is here wrong?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question.  Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54466158/symfony-4-2-how-to-do-a-service-public-only-for-tests/54483081#54483081

Answer (score 0):

Do you user the file services_test.yaml?

I add there all services, which need to be included in tests I show you part of my file:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        public: true

    # If you need to access services in a test, create an alias
    # and then fetch that alias from the container. As a convention,
    # aliases are prefixed with test. For example:
    #
    # test.App\Service\MyService: '@App\Service\MyService'

    test.app.service.user_management.user_service:
        alias: App\Service\UserManagement\UserService

    test.app.service.weight.weight_service:
        alias: App\Service\Weight\WeightService
```

When you do that the rest should fall in place.

Comment: if you write `_defaults: public: true`, it works. But it also should work without `public: true`